# asp.net built runtime Menu with offsite link

Tags: asp.net

I hope you can help me. First, I'd like to tell you I am a desktop app guy, which means I mostly develop my apps in desktop. Now I am trying to build some web app but it leads me to am not sure if confusion or just am doing it wrong.

I have a code here that it **populates a menu at runtime**. Runtime because they the menu items are populated at code behind and the items are fetched in database.

here's the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Menus menu = new Menus();
        imgMainLogo.ImageUrl = VARIABLES.MainLogoImage;
        menu.PopulateMenuControl(ref mainmenu, 2);
        menu.PopulateMenuControl(ref footermenu, 9);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("link: " + footermenu.SelectedValue);
        if (footermenu.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(footermenu.SelectedValue, true);
        }
    }
}
```

and the code in PopulateMenuControl

```
public void PopulateMenuControl(ref Menu menucontrol, int menuparentid)
{
    //menucontrol.Items.Clear();

    foreach (MenuFields mf in GetMenusByParentID(menuparentid))
    {
        MenuItem menuitem = new MenuItem(mf.MenuName, ReplaceSystemNameLink(mf.Link));
        menucontrol.Items.Add(menuitem);

        foreach (MenuFields cmf in GetMenusByParentID(mf.MenuID))
        {
            MenuItem childmenuitem = new MenuItem(cmf.MenuName, ReplaceSystemNameLink(cmf.Link));
            menuitem.ChildItems.Add(childmenuitem);
        }
    }
}
```

So `Page.IsPostBack` is the very basic thing I should learn when doing something in a page. But the problem here is, one of my menu item in "footermenu" has an offsite link, and it should redirect the page into my blog.. but what's happening was, `footermenu.SelectedValue` is empty once I clicked on the "Blog" link.

What's going on?

---

UPDATE

I have updated the code still stuck, the SelectedValue is still empty

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Page_Load IsPostBack: " + Page.IsPostBack.ToString());
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if(footermenu.SelectedValue != null) 
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("link: " + footermenu.SelectedValue);
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Page_Init IsPostBack: " + Page.IsPostBack.ToString());
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Menus menu = new Menus();
        imgMainLogo.ImageUrl = VARIABLES.MainLogoImage;
        menu.PopulateMenuControl(ref mainmenu, 2);
        menu.PopulateMenuControl(ref footermenu, 9);
    }
}
```

Comment: got it working by using "Page_PreRender"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

With dynamic controls (created and added in code), you need to re-create them on every page load - this is best done in the `init` event handler.

Comment: Thank you. Will try and get back here

Comment: Oded. I have updated the question. What I means was populate the menu at runtime.

Comment: @Nullstr1ng - That's fine, I understood that. My answer relates to exactly the issue you are having.

Comment: @Nullstr1ng - Drop the `IsPostback` check in `Page_Init`. What happens  now on a post back is that you are **not** re-creating the menus.